# Is there a way to only print part of a JSON string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have JSON data which I have gotten from weather api. Within the data I would like to be able to display the weather for each hour.

```html
     "hour": [
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1621897200,
                        "time": "2021-05-25 00:00",
                        "temp_c": 8.4,
                        "temp_f": 47.1,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 22.1,
                        "wind_kph": 35.6,
                        "wind_degree": 319,
                        "wind_dir": "NW",
                        "pressure_mb": 1011.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.3,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 87,
                        "cloud": 37,
                        "feelslike_c": 4.1,
                        "feelslike_f": 39.4,
                        "windchill_c": 4.1,
                        "windchill_f": 39.4,
                        "heatindex_c": 8.4,
                        "heatindex_f": 47.1,
                        "dewpoint_c": 6.3,
                        "dewpoint_f": 43.3,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 32.9,
                        "gust_kph": 52.9,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1621900800,
                        "time": "2021-05-25 01:00",
                        "temp_c": 8.3,
                        "temp_f": 46.9,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
```

From the above JSON data I would like to get the time. For some reason the date and time are given within the JSON.

As shown below I am able to get both the date and time from the JSON but I would only like to display the time. Is there any way that I can do this?

```js
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: api + "forecast.json?key=" + apiKey + "&q=" + position.coords.latitude+ "," + position.coords.longitude,
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 0,
      success: (parsed_json) => {
        console.log(parsed_json);
        const time = parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['time'];
        
        const timeText = document.getElementById("title");
        timeText.innerText = time;
       
      }
    });
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to split on blank sign `const time = "2021-05-25 00:00".split(" ")[1]` ->
`const dateAndTime = parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['time']; const timeOnly = dateAndTime.split(" ")[1]`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Can you add this as an answer and I will mark it has a best answer.

Comment: I have added it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to split on blank sign

basic example:

```
const timeOnly = "2021-05-25 00:00".split(" ")[1];
```

your case:

```
const dateAndTime = parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['hour'][0]['time'];
const timeOnly = dateAndTime.split(" ")[1];
```